# One of RGB value is always 255 - ANDROID

Tags: java, android, colors, bluetooth, rgb

I wrote a simple application that shows you RGB values of touched color from image.
The problem is, everytime i touch my image one of RGB values is 255.
For example. I should have values #F0F0F0 i have #FFF0F0 or #F0FFF0.

Here's my code:

```java
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mTextLog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        int x = 0, y = 0;
        float fx, fy;
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            v.getWidth();
            v.getHeight();
            bitmap.getWidth();
            bitmap.getHeight();
            fx = ((event.getX()/656)*960);
            fy = ((event.getY()/721)*1029);
            if(fx > 950) fx = 950;
            if(fy > 1000) fy = 1000;
            if(fx < 32) fx = 32;
            x = Math.round(fx);
            y = Math.round(fy);

            if(fx > 0 && fy > 0){

            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
            int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
            int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
            int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
            if(redValue > 255) redValue = 255;
            if(redValue < 0) redValue = 0;
            if(greenValue > 255) greenValue = 255;
            if(greenValue < 0) greenValue = 0;
            if(blueValue > 255) blueValue = 255;
            if(blueValue < 0) blueValue = 0;

            br = (byte) redValue;
            bg = (byte) greenValue;
            bb = (byte) blueValue;

            tv2.setText("Red: " + redValue + " Green: " + greenValue + " Blue: " + blueValue);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.idd);
            rl.setBackgroundColor(pixel);
```

Another problem is when I moving my finger on screen, chaning color on background is fine, but when i'm trying to send it to my microkontroler via bluetooth there's a problem.
Fe. if i touch black color two times, it sends first black, then blue. :O

It happens only when i return true from this onTouch method.

I would be greatful for any help.

And btw. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed few lines and the problem still exist.

> ```
>           int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
>           int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
>           int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
>           int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
>           hcolor = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(pixel).array();
>           br = (byte) redValue;
>           bg = (byte) greenValue;
>           bb = (byte) blueValue;
>
>           //tv2.setText("Red: " + redValue + " Green: " + greenValue >+ " Blue: " + blueValue);
>           tv2.setText("A: " + hcolor[0] + " R: " + hcolor[1] + " G: " >+ hcolor[2] + " B: " + hcolor[3]);
> ```

My textview shows me fe. that: "A: -1 R: -1 G: 25 B: -7" on pink color.
It's impossible to have 2 of 3 RGB values equals -1 if i touched somewhere else than on white.

There's code i use to send color to microcontroler.
"H" is my "key" that uC understands as "Now there'll be a RGB values"

> if(mConnectedThread != null){
>
> ```
>               mConnectedThread.write(h);
>               try {
>                   Thread.sleep(5);
>               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               }
>               mConnectedThread.write(br);
>               try {
>                   Thread.sleep(5);
>               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               }
>               mConnectedThread.write(bg);
>               try {
>                   Thread.sleep(5);
>               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               }
>               mConnectedThread.write(bb);
>               try {
>                   Thread.sleep(5);
>               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               }
> ```
>
> When I'm returning "false" from this onTouch method nothing wrong happens.
>   I just want to touch and move my finger to change color of RGB lamp in real time.
>   Here's my image i'm using in application.
>   [click](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/6385/1yvo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see some conflicts(Strange!) in your code. first one, if you calculate the colors correctly, so there is no need for checking the values if greater than 255 or less than 0, I mean these lines.

```
    if(redValue > 255) redValue = 255;
    if(redValue < 0) redValue = 0;
    if(greenValue > 255) greenValue = 255;
    if(greenValue < 0) greenValue = 0;
    if(blueValue > 255) blueValue = 255;
    if(blueValue < 0) blueValue = 0;
```

and (maybe) image(that working on) color type is different as you expected, as your example mentioned `black` then `blue`, maybe this is because the code except the last byte as Alpha or vice versa.
my suggestion is change the image and have another try, or use the following code to ensure which byte is representing the alpha value.
if the image is `image/jpeg` so the alpha should be `0xFF(255)` all the time.

```
byte[] hcolor;
hcolor=ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(pixel).array();
out(hcolor[0]);//the first byte represent the alpha, so it should be 255.
```

just have a try and come back and report, we need to fix it.